# Why the button doesn't working on a UI Component Admin Form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform, custom-button

I'm trying to create a **Button Field** on a **UI Component Admin Form** but it looks like it's not calling the Controller. It doesn't call the custom controller,But it works when i call the defaults of Magento (save, delete, back, reset), why?.

What could it be?

Button field code

```
<button name="delete_header">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">custom-button-class</item>
            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">api_data_form.api_data_form_data_source</item>
                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">api/data/deleteheader</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <displayAsLink>false</displayAsLink>
        <title translate="true">Delete Selected Header</title>
    </settings>
</button>
```

Comment: where u are defining this button?

Comment: In the form.xml

Comment: where u have put this form.xml file?

Comment: view/ adminhtml/ ui_component/ form.xml       The form is working good, but this custom button looks like is not calling right the controller.

Comment: you have defined api/data/deleteheader url, what is your frontname?

Comment: the frontname definied in routes.xml is "api" and the name is "Hub_Api"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109827/discussion-between-rafael-fagundes-and-sudo55).

Answer (score 0):

This Works Fine ...Try This Out..

```
 <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
            </item>
        </item>
```

Comment: I tried this and shows this exception: Element 'item': This element is not expected.

Comment: Follow This Link This Works Perfectly Fine...[https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-admin-grid-magento-2/]

Comment: And Also...You can declare buttons inside the

<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

Comment: Actually i don't know if this will help, because i'm creating a ui component admin form with fieldsets.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
<button name="add_address" component="Magento_Customer/js/address/default-address">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
            <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">add-new-address-button</item>
            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.customer_address_update_modal.update_customer_address_form_loader</item>
                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">destroyInserted</item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.customer_address_update_modal</item>
                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">openModal</item>
                </item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.customer_address_update_modal.update_customer_address_form_loader</item>
                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">render</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <title translate="true">Add New Address</title>
        <imports>
            <link name="parentId">${ $.provider}:data.customer_id</link>
        </imports>
    </settings>
</button>
```

**Reference Path: magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml**